# How to stop/remove a sequence in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am using SpriteKit's `playSoundFileNamed` to play a series of sound clips in sequential order.  The problem is that when I exit the `PlayingState` to stop.  Unlike `SKAudioNode`, I can't name and enumerate them. Because the sound clips are `SKAction`s, I can run them and assign a key and stop them individually, however when I add them into a `sequence` like below, the sound does not stop when the state is exited.  How can I stop the `sequence`?

```
class PlayingState: GKState {


    unowned let scene: GameScene  

     var kQuoteNum = 6


    init(scene: SKScene) {
        self.scene = scene as! GameScene
        super.init()
    }

    override func didEnterWithPreviousState(previousState: GKState?) {


        //Build array of quotes from resources folder
        var quoteArray = [SKAction]()

        for i in 0..<kQuoteNum {
            quoteArray.append(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("quote\(i).wav", waitForCompletion: true))

            }



        //Sound
        scene.runAction(SKAction.sequence(quoteArray), withKey: "playQuotes")


    }

    override func willExitWithNextState(nextState: GKState) {
        scene.removeActionForKey("playQuotes")
    }
}
```